# ExtJS 5.0 - adding button as overlay to component

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

We are working with software supplied by a third party, and we are not allowed to modify it, can use only overrides.

I would like to create a new button and overlay it on top of a text input so that they are close together.

I'm having trouble getting the overlay to align, instead it appears top left on the screen. So of course it doesn't align to the text input. Sample code is below, in this case implemented in the view `initComponent` override after `this.callParent([]);` is called.

```
var viewport = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('viewport')[0];
var overlay = viewport.add({
    xtype: 'panel',
    fullscreen: true,
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 120,
    height: 40,
    items:[{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Find Address',
        handler: function() {
            alert('Got it!');
        }
    }],
    styleHtmlContent: true
});
var textField = this.query('*[itemId=textField]')[0];
overlay.showBy(textField, 'c-c?');
```

I've tried using `floating: true` and lots of other approaches.

Once I get it to position properly, is there a way to have the button respond to tab order correctly? That is, tab out of the text field, then have the button get focus?

Comment: Is the third party software also ExtJs? Can you tell something more about that software?

Comment: @Tarabass - Yes, ExtJS 5.0, build release so minimal debug capabilities.

Comment: You can then access the source code and find the class of the form? You could create an override? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-override

Comment: What are your limitations? It's probably better to take the field, replace it with a container that contains the field + the button in a hbox layout.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli - After seeing how much work is involved, I tend to agree. I just got familiar with the peculiarities of the move commands, so will look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your question, you have trouble with setting position to a component. If it is the problem, you can set xy coordinate. Look at this fiddle: 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tpl

```
viewport.down('#idOverlay').setXY([150, 140]);
```

Edit:

```
    Ext.define('OverriddenViewport', {
        override: 'ExampleViewPort',
        initComponent: function() {
            // Set up first
            this.callParent([]);
            this.add(overlay);
            this.addListener('afterrender', function(viewport) {
                viewport.down('#idOverlay').setXY([220,50]);
                viewport.down('#idButton').addListener('blur', function(button) {
                    viewport.down('#idTextfield').focus();
                    console.log('textfield is focussed');
                });
                viewport.down('#idTextfield').addListener('blur', function(button) {
                    viewport.down('#idButton').focus();
                    console.log('button is focussed');
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: The twiddle works okay, but I'm getting errors in the initComponent override, `setXY` is not available.

Comment: Now, you can check the fiddle again. It works as you wish.

Comment: Thank you. I'm guessing to get the button to follow the component when you resize or scroll is a lot of work? Given how much is involved, next time I'm going to look into Evan Trimboli's suggestion to just do a replacement of the component. To add a kafkaesque element to the posting, standards and compliance has just overridden UI/UX and are asking for the action to be invoked upon TAB and ENTER as opposed to a button! So I don't need to worry about this any more...

Comment: You are right. Each time, searching button and get button is not proper way. I thought you didnt have permission to change the code if there is no permission to modify as mention your question. So, I just created  and used overriden panel without modifying main panel.  I agree Even Trimboli's suggestion. If possible, you should pick that way. And implementing that way is also easier than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the source (just to look around) you maybe can create an override of the corresponding class. Create a override, and copy all of the code of the class (form?) into your override.

Here some additional info about creating overrides in ExtJs:
http://moduscreate.com/writing-ext-js-overrides/
https://sencha.guru/2014/12/04/abstract-vs-override/

In your override create a [trigger](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-triggers) (on the field you want to expand)  with your functionality:

```
{
    fieldLabel: 'My Custom Field',
    triggers: {
        foo: {
            cls: 'my-foo-trigger',
            handler: function() {
                console.log('foo trigger clicked');
            }
        }
    }
}
```